# Pass bool property value issue to make auto select checkbox using ASP.NET MVC and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to auto select two checkboxes of the files named "File1" and "File2" that have the job order type of 1 or 2 or 3 when the page is open. I use a property bool type in the Model to return true if the "File1" and "File2" are found in a For loop. But somehow, all the checkboxes of other files are automatically checked, it should be only the checkboxes for the "File1" and "File2." Here are my codes:

Web.Config

```
<appsettings>
   <add key="JobOrderType" value="1,2,3"/>
</appsettings>
```

CustomerDocument.cs - my view model

```
public class CustomerDocument
{
    public bool IncludeInEmail { get; set; }
    public long DocumentId { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string DocumentPath { get; set; }
    public bool IsAutoSelectFile { get; set; }
}
```

ShowJobTypeController.cs

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ShowJobType() {
        try
        {
             //Make auto select for File1 and File2 for some certain job order types            
             List<CustomerCustomers> customerDocuments;
             var myQuery = dbTest2.JobOrders.FirstOrDefault(z => z.Id == JobOrderId);

             var jobOrderTypeId = new List<int>();
             var configJOTypeValues = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["JobOrderType"].Split(',');

                    for (var i = 0; i < configJOTypeValues.Length; i++)
                    {
                        var IdValue = 0;
                        if (int.TryParse(configJOTypeValues[i], out IdValue))
                            jobOrderTypeId.Add(IdValue);
                    }

                    ViewBag.IsAutoSelectFileForJobOrder = false;
                    var vmCustomerDoc = new ViewModels.CustomerDocument();
                    var isDocSelected = false;

                    foreach (var doc in customerDocuments)
                    {
                        if (doc != null && jobOrderTypeId.Contains(myQuery.JobTypeId) && (doc.DocumentName.Contains("File1") || doc.DocumentName.Contains("File2")))
                        {
                            vmCustomerDoc.IsAutoSelectFile = true;
                            isDocSelected = vmPCustomerDoc.IsAutoSelectFile;

                            ViewBag.IsAutoSelectFileForJobOrder = isDocSelected;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                           vmCustomerDoc.IsAutoSelectFile = false;
                           ViewBag.IsAutoSelectFileForJobOrder = isDocSelected;
                        }
                    }

        }
        catch 
        {
            //Leave it empty
        }


return View();                  
}
```

ShowJobType.cshtml

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "ViewJobType";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

 var docs = ViewBag.CustomerDocuments as List<VM.CustomerDocument>; //Links to CustomerDocument.cs View Model
 <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Check to Include in Email</th>
        <th>Files</th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var doc in docs)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
         @{
            var docValue = doc.DocumentId + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(doc.DocumentPath) ? "" : "/" + doc.DocumentPath);
          }

            <input type="checkbox" name="DocEmail" id="DocEmail" value="@docValue" @(ViewBag.IsAutoSelectGuideForJobOrder) ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "") />
        </td>
    </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Comment: Your ViewBag value for `IsAutoSelectGuideForJobOrder` is being written to on each iteration on the back end. You're not storing a value for each entry, you're storing one value for all entries. You have the `IsAutoSelectFile` property on your view model, can you use that to set the checked value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `ViewBag.CustomerDocuments` has the view models that have been updated to set their `IsAutoSelectFile` property, you can change your logic for displaying checks to check for that property value on each document and use it to add the check to the input field.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="DocEmail" id="DocEmail" value="@docValue" @(doc.IsAutoSelectFile) ? "checked" : "") />
```

Additionally, in your current logic in the back end, once `isDocSelected` is set to true, it will always be true. If you use the ViewModel's property instead of the view bag, you can remove it's usage from your logic anyways.

Comment: Yep, I got it. Thanks a lot for your helping me and pointing that out!